# web scraping multiple urls for H1 tags using a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am stuck trying to implement a python 3 program.
What I am trying to do is web scrape printer page (http://192.168.1.10 for example which is hp laser jet for example) I am trying to make a scraper that will go to about 20 different urls with printer pages and grab the H1 tags where the printer model is stored in tag.

I am new to python, and I would like to use a txt file with urls and use a for loop to use the url as a varible.

my current code is like this and works for single url, but i dont know how to word what I am looking for to figure out how to use a text file and each line as a varible.

here is url text file for example:

```
http://192.168.1.10
http://192.168.1.11
http://192.168.1.12
...etc one url per line
```

My python 3 code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://192.168.1.10/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find(class_='mastheadTitle')

pagehp = page.find_all('h1')

for page in pagehp:
    print(page.prettify())
```

use line here:

```
page = requests.get('http://192.168.1.10/')
```

How can I change that to my urls.txt and make it a loop so it uses each url on each line as that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python `open` module like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_file = "url_file.txt" #The URL should be written one per line in the url_file.txt file
```

## Now let's read urls from the url_file.txt

```
with open(url_file, "r") as f:
  url_pages = f.read()
# we need to split each urls into lists to make it iterable
pages = url_pages.split("\n") # Split by lines using \n

# now we run a for loop to visit the urls one by one
for single_page in pages:
  page = requests.get(single_page.strip())
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
  page = soup.find(class_='mastheadTitle')

  pagehp = page.find_all('h1')

  for page in pagehp:
      print(page.prettify())
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain the logic behind this? Im trying to wrap my head around what the code is doing. Or is there a very simplistic article on python? I will keep digging. Thank you for your time

Comment: Ok, what happened there is that we open the .txt first with the `open` module, the file argument is the file path while the second argument is the mode 'r' indicates the we want to read the file. Before we start the scraping, we split the urls in to lists to make it iterable, and the we run a `for` loop on each urls

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i needed to know, spliting it into list

Comment: Ok, you are welcome. Don't forget to mark as answer if you find it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("urls.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        page = requests.get(line.strip())
        ...
```